# Can Gson deserialize using class builder?

Tags: java, jackson, gson, builder

Does anyone know if I can make Gson use my class builder vs the constructor when deserialzing my class?

I know I can use builder with Jackson with something like the following:

```
@JsonDeserialize( builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class )
@Builder
@Value
public class MyClass
{
    @NonNull
    private final String myValue;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder( withPrefix = "" )
    public static final class MyClassBuilder{}
}
```

Is there something similar to @JsonPOJOBuilder for Gson that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a case like this you'll probably want to [write a custom deserializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer) that parses the JSON and invokes your builder. If your builder was a POJO with concrete fields you could instead just call `.fromJson(json, Builder.class)` and then build the `MyClass` instance from that, but I don't think that will work here.

In general this doesn't seem like a good place to use Gson (or Jackson, take your pick). The purpose of Gson is to use a Java class structure to represent a JSON schema, and then support easily transforming between the two. You *can* massage Gson into supporting other use cases like this one, but the benefits become less clear. Personally, I would just create a POJO that encodes the schema you're trying to parse and go from there, rather than spend the time making Jackson and Gson play nice together.

That said a general solution is also possible. A quick search uncovered a [Gson adapter](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson) for [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto), so you could either use AutoValue instead or do something similar for Jackson.